# Javascript calculator not evaluating in the input

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make my own simple short javascript calculator, but i seem to have taken different approach than any tutorial i found and i cant find a mistake in my code .

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset = 'utf-8'>
</head>

<html>
<body>
  <input name='x' onchange='this.value=eval(this.value)'>
<br>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<br>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
<br>
<button>7</button>
<button>8</button>
<button>9</button>
<br>
<button>0</button>
<button>.</button>
<button>+</button>
<br>
<button>*</button>
<button>/</button>
<button id='enter'>=</button>

<script>
function el(x){return document.querySelector(x);}
function els(x){return document.querySelectorAll(x);}

var x=el("input");
function g(){x.value+=this.innerHTML;}
var t = els("button");
  for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){
  t[i].onclick=g;
}
```

I think the problem are those lines, but I'm not sure how to correct it

```
  el('#enter').onclick=x;
  el("input").innerHTML=eval(t);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, you've taken a different approach. What's the question? Is it not working correctly? If so, *how* is it not working correctly? What results are you seeing that you don't expect?

Comment: Why would you set `onclick` to the `input` element? Why would you set `innerHTML` to `eval(t)` when `t` is a collection of elements?

Comment: Start with an approach that makes sense. Logic shown sure doesn't and we aren't here to write this whole thing for you

Comment: @charlietfl: Actually, most of the above is just fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two lines you've flagged up are certainly a problem, they don't make any sense at all. You can't set `onclick` to an `HTMLInputElement`, and calling `eval` on a collection of elements (`t`) doesn't make any sense.

Other than that, your basic approach is sound. You just want the handler on the `=` button to do the same thing you had in your `change` handler. Since you want them to do the same thing, put that logic in a function both of them call:

```
function calcuate() {
    x.value = eval(x.value);
}
```

then:

```
el('#enter').onclick = calcuate;
```

and

```
<input name="x" onchange="calcuate();">
```

With that change, it's fine:

```js
function el(x) {
  return document.querySelector(x);
}

function els(x) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(x);
}

var x = el("input");

function g() {
  x.value += this.innerHTML;
}
var t = els("button");
for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
  t[i].onclick = g;
}

function calculate() {
  x.value = eval(x.value);
}

el('#enter').onclick = calculate;
```

```html
<input name='x' onchange="calculate();">
<br>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<br>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
<br>
<button>7</button>
<button>8</button>
<button>9</button>
<br>
<button>0</button>
<button>.</button>
<button>+</button>
<br>
<button>*</button>
<button>/</button>
<button id='enter'>=</button>
```

---

Having said that, using `onxyz` attribute-style event handlers on setting `onxyz` style properties works, but isn't best practice. The attribute ones require that your functions be global (and globals are a Bad Thing™), and while the property ones don't have that problem, they do only allow a single handler for the event to be attached to the element.  Look at using `addEventListener` instead.

---

Side note: You're fine with your `button` elements because they're not in a form, but beware that the **surprising** default `type` for `button` is `submit`. So `<button>X</button>` will submit a form. If you just want a button and it may be in a form, you need `<button type="button">X</button>`.